# How to compile Xperia S kernel wifi modules

Tags: kernel, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a kernel compiled from source for Xperia S ICS frimware, it runs very smooth, the only problem is there are no wifi modules when I add certain features.

I've tried different things, but I never get the modules.

So I can't use wifi with my kernel.

Please explain how I can compile them or what do I need to add to a file in the kernel source?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Xperia S DoomKernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1557452), sources are available [here](https://github.com/DooMLoRD/android_kernel_semc_msm8660). Author provides WiFi modules as well.

The reason why OEM's does not provide all source code (for example, some vendor drivers) is that they are covered by proprietary license, and are not supposed to be shared with community.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:
1. The easy way: Open your .config file and change CONFIG_LOCALVERSION how to make it same as your previous kernel. By this way, your kernel can use the exist wifi module.
2. Compile your module by yourself: 
   2.1 After compile kernel, go to wifi driver folder and type

```
KERNEL_DIR=<your kernel dir> CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- ARCH=arm make
```

If you use the official wifi source code, you need compile by difference command

```
KLIB_BUILD=<your kernel dir> KLIB=. CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- ARCH=arm make
```

2.2 Copy your .ko files to /system/lib/modules/
NOTE: If your new module not work, the easy way to fix is enable 80211 and WL12XX in your .config file (to provide needed object and function)